# Polymer icons not showing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, meteor, polymer

I am using Meteor as my backend and Polymer as the frontend. I have imported my icons but they are not showing in Chrome:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
```

They only show in Safari and Firefox on Mac 10.10.3. Chrome version is 43.0

This does not work in Chrome:

```
<paper-icon-button icon="favorite"></paper-icon-button>
```

I have cleared all cache and restarted both server and mac but only shows in firefox and safari. Im about to reinstall this MBP as Im losing more hairs in my young age.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Polymer 1.0 default icon set in iron-icons not working using blaze (meteor) templating engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608194/polymer-1-0-default-icon-set-in-iron-icons-not-working-using-blaze-meteor-temp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of this. They are working on a fix, in the meantime you can use this solution in this thread:

[Polymer 1.0 default icon set in iron-icons not working using blaze (meteor) templating engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608194/polymer-1-0-default-icon-set-in-iron-icons-not-working-using-blaze-meteor-temp/30713035#30713035)

Comment: Thank you. Never knew about the duplicate and that is a known issue.