# Polymer - Default icon set in iron-icons don't show up but all other sets work

Tags: html, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

### Summary

I'm working on a Polymer project based off the Polymer starter kit, and I ran into a problem where icons from the default icon set aren't appearing. Their size and style is calculated correctly, but there's no SVG within the tag when I use inspect element. I've tried icons from `maps` and `social` which all work, but the ones from `icons` just don't have an image.

I've tried various different solutions:

1. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608194/polymer-1-0-default-icon-set-in-iron-icons-not-working-using-blaze-meteor-temp) Stack Overflow question here, I did the accepted solution with no results.
2. I deleted all of my Polymer components and did a fresh `bower install` + `bower update`. Still no go.
3. I saw somewhere that the Polymer Starter Kit has a conflict with the `my-icons.html` file, so I renamed it to `custom-icons.html`. This also didn't work.

This is very confusing and frustrating because the problem seemed to pop up out of nowhere. One day the default iron-icons were working, and the next they weren't.

---

### My imports

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer/app-drawer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-header/app-header.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-header-layout/app-header-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-scroll-effects/app-scroll-effects.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html">

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-route/app-location.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-route/app-route.html">

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/maps-icons.html">

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-localstorage/iron-localstorage.html">

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-icon-item.html">

<link rel="import" href="app-data.html">
<link rel="import" href="log-out.html">
<link rel="import" href="custom-icons.html">
```

---

### Utilization

```
<a href="/#/home-quotes" tabindex="-1">
  <paper-icon-item>
    <iron-icon icon="icons:settings" item-icon></iron-icon> <!-- This doesn't work -->
    Home
  </paper-icon-item>
</a>
<a href="/#/secret-quotes" hidden$="[[!storedUser.loggedin]]" tabindex="-1">
  <paper-icon-item>
    <iron-icon icon="maps:add-location" item-icon></iron-icon> <!-- This works? -->
    Secret Quotes
  </paper-icon-item>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** The bug has been fixed in Polymer Starter Kit 2.1.1. Now when you run `polymer init starter-kit`, the generated codebase will include the fix.

---

I suspect the problem is a naming conflict with your iconset ([Issue #934](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/issues/934)), which was recently fixed.

Before the fix, the [name of the custom iconset in Polymer Starter Kit](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/1254d28/src/my-icons.html#L14) was `icons`, which is unfortunately also the [name of the default iconset](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-icons/blob/22dbf98/iron-icons.html#L41) from `<iron-icons>`. Since your `custom-icons.html` import occurs after `iron-icons.html`, your iconset takes precedence.

The fix is to rename your custom icons to avoid the name conflict, allowing for both iconsets to coexist. That is, change the iconset's `name` attribute in your `custom-icons.html` to something like this:

```
<iron-iconset-svg name="my-custom-icons" size="24">
```

Comment: @NeonWizard No problem :)